# Custom intro text in joomla 3.5

Tags: joomla

I am trying to make the intro text is seperated and isn't extracted from the full text of Joomla 3.5.
To do that: I make a

```
<div class="intro-custom">the content that i need to show as intro-text</div>
```

, 
put this  at the top position of each article and use CSS  to hide in display content.
But i dont know how to bring

```
  <div class="intro-custom">
```

this to the front.
I found this file components/com-contents/view/category/tmpl/default_articles.php

```
<?php
$text = $article->introtext;
$text = preg_replace('@<div[^>]*class=(["\'])mosimage_caption\\1[^>]*>[^>]*          </div>@', '', $text );
$preserv = "";
  $text = strip_tags($text, /* exclude */ $preserv );
  $text = preg_replace("@<script[^>]*?>.*?</script>@si","",$text);
  $text = preg_replace('/{.+?}/','',$text);
  $text = preg_replace('/(( )|(&nbsp;))+/',' ',$text);
  $text = preg_replace('/&quot;/',' ',$text);
  $text = str_replace(array("\r\n", "\n", "\r"), "", $text);
  $text = str_replace("caption","", $text);
  $shorttext = substr($text,0,300);
  echo '<p>' . $shorttext . '...</p><p><a href="' . JRoute::_(ContentHelperRoute::getArticleRoute($article->slug, $article->catid)) . '">Read more</a></p>';
?>
```

I just know CSS and HTML, any help?

Answer (score 0):

### Template override

First thing, use [template override](http://template%20override) so that your changes will not be overwritten at next Joomla update. In your case, this means that you need to create a folder:

```
/templates/[YOUR TEMPLATE]/html/com_content/category/
```

and copy the file `default_articles.php` in this folder.

### Edit template

If I understood your question correctly, you want to show always the same intro text for all articles, instead of using the intro text from the article themselves.

So you can remove all the code in the file and replace it with:

```
<div class="intro-custom"> 
    <p>>the content that i need to show as intro-text</p>
    <p><a href="<?= JRoute::_(ContentHelperRoute::getArticleRoute($article->slug, $article->catid)) ?>">Read more</a></p>
</div>
```

You can then adapt HTML / CSS as you like.

Comment: I do not want to show always the same intro text for all articles. I want intro texts are the contents of the <div class="intro-custom">, but these contents are difference for each article (but the div tag are the same). Thank you for your noticing for template override, i have just did it,